# "Misunderstood of" Is "of" the right preposition?

Tags: prepositions

I find a line from a book very strange.

> Arnold Bennett, reviewing it in The New Age (24 October 1908), observed, presciently:
>
> the book is fairly certain to be **misunderstood of** the people . . . The author may call his chief characters the Rat, the Mole, the Toad, — they are human beings, and they are meant to be nothing but human beings...

This extract is from Peter Hunt's introduction to Kenneth Grahame's classic *The Wind in the Willows*. The passage at issue was written by Arnold Bennett. I thought **of** is the wrong preposition. If *the people* here refers to the audience of the book, the public, shouldn't it be *misunderstood **by** the people*? Is this a wrong or archaic usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**the people** there can mean "the characters in it", and **misunderstood of** can be paraphrased as "misunderstood with respect to".

The collocation **understood of** is fairly common in 18th and 19th century academic essays.  It can be complemented by a content clause:

> It may be understood of X *that X is such-and-such...*

There it has the meaning "We can say this about X: ..."

Or the phrase can mean "taken as referring to":

> Those words may be understood of X.

Those words may be understood as referring in particular to X (not to Y).

That said, I don't find the sentence to be very clear. It should be noted that a number of the modernists thought Arnold Bennett was a windbag.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say *the people* here is not the audience. *of* is used to relate the misunderstanding of the book to the people as a subject. That is, the book will be misunderstood as regards its treatment of the people. The explanation about the naming thing afterwards kind of supports that.. .